# iOS 5 Upgrade Needing rootViewController

Tags: objective-c, view, uiviewcontroller, rootview

The App I created for iOS 4 does not work once run on iOS 5.  I am receiving the following error:

"Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch"

How can I update the following code to fix this error?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  

UINavigationController *navcon = [[UINavigationController alloc] init] 
TSViewController *pvc = [[TSViewController alloc] init];

[navcon pushViewController:pvc animated:NO];
[navcon setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    [pvc release];
[window addSubview:navcon.view];


return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`[window setRootViewController:navcon];`  instead of `addSubview`.

Comment: I tried that and now I'm getting the following error  " *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILayoutContainerView _preferredInterfaceOrientationGivenCurrentOrientation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x35d860'"

Comment: Did you make sure you did `[window setRootViewController:navcon];` and NOT `[window setRootViewController:navcon.view];`?

Comment: Yes I tried both ways, however when I use 'navcon' and not 'navcon.view' I still get the "Applications are expected to have a rootViewController" error.

Comment: Sorry, after you call `setRootViewController:` you have to call `[window makeKeyAndVisible]`.